# check values in ng-repeat and $http post it AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I am trying to add a checkboxes in `ng-repeat`, and then post with `$http` checked values.
Here is my code :

```
$scope.add_to_post = function(n){
        console.log("name",n);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param({
                name: n,
            }),
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log('post');
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div >
   <ul ng-repeat="x in messages" style="list-style:none;">
    <li>
     {{x.name}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="add_to_post(x.name)"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
<button ng-click="post()">post</button>
```

I want option that I check some `checkboxes`, then I click `post` and `$http` calls are running.
My plunker : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/zPu9DH0JyinlBvLh
Thanks for answers and help in advance!

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can create an object for storing the models (`ng-model`) for your checkboxes like this:

`$scope.modelCheck = {};`

then in the html you can bind them like this:

`<input type="checkbox" ng-model="modelCheck[x.name]"/>`

finally, when you are going to do the `POST` collect the check boxes name which where marked as `true` like this:

```
$scope.post = function(){
    var data = [];
       for (var k in $scope.modelCheck) {
           // `k` is own property (checkbox name) and its value is `true`
           if ($scope.modelCheck.hasOwnProperty(k) && $scope.modelCheck[k]) {
            data.push({'name': k});
           }
       }
       console.log(data);
       // do with data as you wish from here
    };
```

See this [**Forked working plunker**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/z055SgWWmt6yGHfT) (see the console)